# PHP exec(myexe) fails in PHP App, but not CLI. Fails Running Under User "apache"

Tags: linux, apache, segmentation-fault, exec

I have a custom program (e.g. myexe) being executed by a web app using PHP's exec() function.  It does not fail when run using the PHP CLI nor does myexe fail when run from the command line with me as a user.  I have built myexe so that there are no memory issues when profiled using valgrind.  myexe is about 26MB in size.

To simplify the situation, I have run myexe on the command line under the user 'apache' and reproduced the failure.

```
su -s /bin/sh apache -c "/usr/local/bin/myexe parm1 parm2..."
==> Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

BUT when I change the user to myself and run the same command above, it works.

```
su -s /bin/sh mike -c "/usr/local/bin/myexe parm1 parm2..."
```

==> WORKS

Here's the error from the system log file:

```
Jul  9 18:26:15 DEVSTN-1 kernel: myexe[27352]: segfault at 7fffa2bf9ff8 ip 0000000000410324 sp 00007fffa2bfa000 error 6 in myexe[400000+5ae000]
    Jul  9 18:26:16 DEVSTN-1 abrt[27353]: Saved core dump of pid 27352 (/usr/local/bin/myexe) to /var/spool/abrt/ccpp-2015-07-09-18:26:15-27352 (13631488 bytes)
    Jul  9 18:26:16 DEVSTN-1 abrtd: Directory 'ccpp-2015-07-09-18:26:15-27352' creation detected
    Jul  9 18:26:17 DEVSTN-1 abrtd: Executable '/usr/local/bin/myexe' doesn't belong to any package and ProcessUnpackaged is set to 'no'
    Jul  9 18:26:17 DEVSTN-1 abrtd: 'post-create' on '/var/spool/abrt/ccpp-2015-07-09-18:26:15-27352' exited with 1
    Jul  9 18:26:17 DEVSTN-1 abrtd: Deleting problem directory '/var/spool/abrt/ccpp-2015-07-09-18:26:15-27352'
```

My configuration:

- CentOS6 2.6.32-504.23.4.el6.x86_64
- Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)
- PHP Version 5.3.3

Am I correct with assuming that PHP has nothing to do with the error?
What should I do next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem by entering a bash shell user user apache and running the program using gdb.

Turns out myexe was trying to create a directory under the user's home dir (/home/apache) which doesn't exist.

What helped me was knowing how to start a shell under a different user and using gdb.

Here's the command to start a shell under another user (apache):
su -s /bin/bash apache

Answer (score 0):

Correct; PHP has nothing to do with the error. This is a segmentation fault caused by invalid memory access (either overflowing a buffer, or accessing already-freed memory) in `myexe`. It seems to have saved a [core dump](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_dump) to `/var/spool/abrt/ccpp-2015-07-09-18:26:15-27352`, so, try [debugging with GDB](http://www.unknownroad.com/rtfm/gdbtut/gdbsegfault.html):

```
gdb /usr/local/bin/myexe -c /var/spool/abrt/ccpp-2015-07-09-18:26:15-27352

(gdb) bt
```

And try to see where the executable is failing. To get useful output, it will need to be compiled with debugging symbols. If it doesn't fail running as root or a different user, or running in an interactive terminal, I'd look for bugs that could be triggered by being unable to open a file, unable to read an expected environment variable, etc. to help isolate your problem.

Running the executable under `strace` might help figure out what's going on as well.